# systems of equations with one inequality and exponents.

Tags: inequality, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have a systems of equations for a website that relies on the solution. I have just read up on the subject online but I still can't come to a conclusion. The equation is this:

$$8000 \lt xy^5 \lt 8100$$
$$xy^4 - xy^3 \gt 5000$$

I have no idea how to solve for the greater then or less then part of the equation. I also have no idea how to solve for exponents and finally if it even can be solved! all help is greatly appreciated! thank you for your answer!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has no lasting value.

Answer (score 2):

The system you have is not solvable.

Since we don't know the exact values of $xy^5$ and $xy^4-xy^3$, let's put in some values, say $r$ and $s$, and see what happens.  We have:
$$xy^5 = r \tag{1}$$
$$xy^4 -xy^3 = s \tag{2}$$
$$8000 < r < 8100$$
$$s > 5000$$

We know that $y \not= 0$, since otherwise $r$ would equal zero, contradicting the fact that $r > 8000 > 0$.  Thus, from (1), we can find
$$x = \frac{r}{y^5} \tag{3}$$

Substituting (3) into (2) gives
$$ry^{-1} - ry^{-2} = s$$
which we can multiply by $y^2$ to get
$$ry - r = sy^2$$
$$0 = sy^2 - ry + r \tag{4}$$

I'm not sure if you're familiar with the [quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation), but we can use the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant) to tell when (4) will have solutions.  Specifically, (4) will have (real) solutions when (and only when!)
$$r^2 - 4rs > 0$$
But, we know that $s > 5000$, so
$$r^2 - 4rs < r^2 -4r(5000)$$
$$r^2 - 4rs < r(r-20000)$$
But, for $8000 < r < 8100$, the right hand side is always negative, so our discriminant is always less than zero, and we have no real solutions.